# Dirac bundle and Frobenius theoram

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

We know that for any distribution W in TM, one can associate the Lagrangian subbundle. In this case how can I prove this statement?"This subbundle is dirac if and only if  W is involutive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lagrangian Subbundle $L \subset \mathbb{T} M$ is defined as a Dirac structure if it is involutive. So, for any $a_1, a_2 \in \Gamma(L)$
$$[a_1, a_2, ] \in \Gamma(L)$$
Where $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the *Dorfman bracket*. The Dorfman bracket in general is not a Lie bracket, in the sense that $(\Gamma(\mathbb{T}M), [\cdot, \cdot])$ is not
a Lie algebra, because the bracket is not skew-symmetric, although one can show that it is skew-symmetric up to an exact form $$[a_1, a_2] + [a_2, a_1]=d(a_1,a_2) \tag{*}$$

So denote by $\text{Dir}(M)$ *all* the Dirac structures on $M$, you need to show that for  $a_1, a_2 \in \Gamma(L)$ 
$$(a_1,a_2)=0$$
and by (*) one has that the bracket is skew-symmetric on $\Gamma(L)$, hence one can show that $[a_1, a_2] = -[a_2,a_1]$ and $(\Gamma(\mathbb{T}M), [\cdot, \cdot])$ can be then shown to be a Lie algebra.

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot. But I have some problems with your answer: First of all why do you call the first bracket “dorfman”? Is n’t “courant bracket”? My second question is about (*) formula, would you please explain it more? I’ll be grateful,If you make an example about this formula.

Comment: I call it a Dorfman bracket as I am working within the sections of $\mathbb{T}M$ (actually on $\mathbb{T}M \bigoplus \mathbb{T}^{*}M$); the relation in (*) arises precisely from the axioms of a Courant Lie Algebroid. This is just a vector bundle $E \mapsto M$ with a bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]: \Gamma E \times \Gamma E \mapsto \Gamma E$. This bracket is the  Dorfman bracket.

Comment: The Courant bracket is just the antisymmetrization of the Dormfam bracket.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have other questions!